# I'm a bit confused on npm publishing workflow. Do I have this right?

Tags: jenkins, npm, release

I'm working on an **npm module** and the workflow for publishing it **(local registry)**.

As I'm going through this, I'm running into a few places of confusion.

My workflow so far:

1. Create pull request from `feature/*` branch into `develop`.
2. Jenkins CI job runs, building and testing `feature/*` branch.
3. Successful build allows pull request merge into `develop`.
4. Jenkins release job manually triggered, passing release type as parameter ('patch', 'minor', 'major'):

   - Checkout `master` branch.
   - Merge `develop` into `master`.
   - Install npm dependencies.
   - Run tests.
   - `npm version "${RELEASE_TYPE}"`
   - [possibly a release notes step here or something]
   - `npm publish`
   - `git push origin master && git push --tags`
   - Email summarizing release sent to team.

What I don't understand is how the version stays in sync between the `develop` and `master` branches. I'm committing the version bump to `master` only. **Would it make sense to setup an auto-merge from `master` to `develop` each time?** That seems a bit backwards.

**BONUS QUESTIONS**:

- What normally takes place during *Step 2*? Currently I'm just running unit tests and linters, but is there more that I should be doing at that step?
- Are there other things I should be doing along the way with my workflow?

Thanks!